# volume of solid formed by $y=1/x$ along $y$ axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Finding volume of solid formed by revolving the area enclosed by curve $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{x},x=2,y=2$ about $y$ axis.

What i try: i try to visualise how the curve is formed.

I formed a solid bucket type figure. Whose inner radius is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ and outer radius is $2$

So the volume $$\int^{2}_{\frac{1}{2}}2\pi\bigg((2)^2-(0.5)^2\bigg)\cdot \frac{3}{2}dx$$

What i have done is right or not. If not please tell me how can i form solid figure of revolution and the integral. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand how the portion of the revolving area in the 4th and 3rd quadrants is supposed to be enclosed.

Answer (score 1):

Cylindrical shells: $\int_{1/2}^22\pi x(1/x)\operatorname dx+\int_0^{1/2}2\pi x(2)\operatorname dx=2π((3/2)+[x^2]_0^{1/2})=7π/2$.